# deploying to heroku issue react app with tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, heroku, tailwind-css

heroku says

```
Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       static/css/main.4fc4cc2a.css from Css Minimizer plugin
       /tmp/build_3c1b41c6/static/css/main.4fc4cc2a.css:2554:73: Unknown word [webpack://./src/index.css:3,0][static/css/main.4fc4cc2a.css:2554,73]
       
       
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: You have to include your configuration files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.